# Switch default python to Anaconda3 version - still not working after changing .bash_profile

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

Trying to change my default python environment to the anaconda version. I'm using mac os high sierra.

I don't have a .bashrc profile, so I have been changing my .bash_profile file and editing the export path as tons of people have said to anaconda3. Here is what my file has right now:

```
export PATH="~/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
# added by Anaconda3 2018.12 installer
# #>>> conda init >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' #!!
#__conda_setup="$(CONDA_REPORT_ERRORS=false #'/anaconda3/bin/conda' shell.bash hook 2> /#dev/null)"
#if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
#    \eval "$__conda_setup"
#else
#    if [ -f "/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
#        . "/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
#        CONDA_CHANGEPS1=false conda activate base
#    else
#        \export PATH="/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
#    fi
#fi
#unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda init <<<
```

I have everything under export PATH commented out, not sure how it got added. When I type which python I get:

```
/usr/bin/python
```

And my default python is still 2.7 and not from anaconda. Whenever I try to run "conda" and anything I get the following error:

```
ERROR: The install method you used for conda--probably either `pip install conda`
or `easy_install conda`--is not compatible with using conda as an application.
If your intention is to install conda as a standalone application, currently
supported install methods include the Anaconda installer and the miniconda
installer.  You can download the miniconda installer from
https://conda.io/miniconda.html.
```

I have tried uninstalling anaconda3 and reinstalling it and re-adding its path to the .bash_profile file but nothing seems to be working. I think that some other type of .bash file must be determining which python is run, but I can't seem to find it.

Any help here would be much appreciated, I really need to be able to run anaconda python for school stuff.

Thanks so much!

Comment: What are the results of `echo $HOME` and `echo $PATH`?